# Is it possible to prevent CPU-intensive scripts in iframes from blocking the outer frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have CPU-intensive scripts in an iframe and it's making the outer frame laggy. Is it possible to somehow prevent this from happening? I can't modify the contents of the iframe.

For example, if I had a page like the following, how do I prevent the outer page from lagging?

```
<iframe srcdoc="Iframe<script>setInterval(function(){for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++);},0)</script>"></iframe>

<button>Click</button>

<script>
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<p>Clicked</p>');
});
</script>
```

If you set the termination condition high enough, it takes a while for the "clicked" message to appear.

**WARNING:** The following JSFiddle may be CPU-intensive. I set the termination condition to 10000000, while my machine starts feeling laggy after 100x that. Be careful on mobile. http://jsfiddle.net/0o2aux06/1/

Comment: Can you explain why you would have this situation on your website? And if we could detect this, would it be okay to simply remove the iframe from the page?

Comment: I need to display news articles in the iframe and many of the news sites use a lot of Javascript. Even if this were a hypothetical problem, would it be possible to solve it using something like Web Workers?

Comment: Your problem is interesting, however I don't think I have a proper solution for you. I'm not sure Web Workers can help.

Comment: Maybe you can consider using a server-side script to parse the external pages and extract the text, then put it on your page.